# Selenium WebDriver test for span

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

I'm actually trying to design a test case for element in the span

```
    <div class="one">
    Annual Salary
    <span>€40,000</span>
    </div>
```

My code is:

```
String expected = "€40,000";
WebElement resultTextBox = MyDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#results1 > div.wrapper > div.one > span"));

String TestResult = resultTextBox.getText();

if (expected.equalsIgnoreCase(TestResult)) {
    System.out.println("Test Case Pass");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Test Case failed");
    MyDriver.close();//close
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It looks correct

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code for WebElement that contains span text as xpath:

```
WebElement resultTextBox = MyDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='€40,000']"));
```

Comment: She won't need she. She needs to get this text and compare it with the expected result.